# Symfony 4 security

Tags: symfony, security

I am trying to add security control to my SF4 app.

According to this [tutorial](http://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html), I found the following issues:

1. `composer require security` prompts error: no package found and suggests `symfony/security` instead.
2. `composer require symfony/security` runs fine but no `security.yaml` was generated during the process.
3. After creating `security.yaml` and adding some lines in it:

`security:
        providers:
            in_memory: { memory: ~ }
        firewalls:
            dev:
                pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
                security: false
            main:
                anonymous: ~
                http_basic: ~
        access_control:
            - {path: ^/admin, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }`

The page loaded with error: `There is no extension able to load the configuration for "security"`.

Anyone can throw in some hints?

Comment: You need to get the security bundle installed.  composer require security is generally all you need but there have times when the symfony recipe server does not work correctly.  composer require symfony/security-bundle should get you to the next step.

Comment: As an alternative, start over and do: "composer create-project symfony/website-skeleton" This will install the framework bundle as well as a number of other basic bundles such as the security bundle.

Comment: Thanks @Cerad. Your method is working.